# Can CH be sorted between C and D?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, collation

I wanted to know if it's possible to use (or create) a collation in PostgreSQL that will sort the letter CH between
C and D.

For example, I would need the sorting as:

```
Angola
Belize
Croatia   -- but, currently Croatia is placed after Chile
Chile
Denmark
```

If there's no built-in collation, maybe I could create a custom one. But I'm a total noob on this; I have never done it and I don't know how easy or difficult this can be. Is creating a collation something I can learn and do in a week or less? Otherwise, maybe I'll need to consider a different strategy, or renegotiate the requirement.

Comment: You will need to check if this is possible with [ICU collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#id-1.6.11.4.5.6.5)

Comment: Is this for a real world language in which such a convention exists? If so, why so coy about naming the language?

Comment: Presumably some clues here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(digraph)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Spanish: CH is a letter, as well as LL and RR (that come next). Then I'll need to tackle tildes Á, É, Í, Ó and Ú; finally I'll tackle dieresis Ü and Ï.

Comment: Ch used to be a letter in Spanish and even dictionaries ordered their words this way, that's no longer valid. Digraphs have been excluded from alphabet as appears here https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/exclusion-de-ch-y-ll-del-abecedario.